# Delphi bidirectional binding for Synedit

Tags: delphi, livebindings

I need to bi-directionaly bind Synedit to column 'text' in database. It works with memo component, but for Synedit or i.e. Richedit is created only one-directional binding.
Value is synchronized from database, but i don't know how to update back to database from Synedit.

I try in the Livebinding designer simple connect fields like on picture, but it i'm stuck in documentation.

[image: scheme]
[image: binding]

I need automatically synchronized database field when i leave editor, like it works with Memo component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that TSynMemo does not behave like TMemo is that 'out of the box' it has no support the LiveBindings `observers`
necessary to make LB work.  The way to overcome this is to derive a TSynMemo
descendent which *does* support LB observers and use that instead.

Luckily, there is an [Embarcadero wiki entry](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Tutorial:_Creating_LiveBindings-Enabled_Components)
which explains how to add LB observers to components which lack them.  Based on that, with a little preparatory settting up,
the example code should do what you want:

- On a new form, drop a TClientDataSet, TDataSource, TDBGrid and a TDNavigator and link them up in the usual way.  Using a TClientDataSet is to allow a completely self-contained sample project.  **Note** If you want to use FireDAC. you can equally well use a TFDMemTable instead of a TClientDataSet; the steps and code below will be identical, and I've tested that this FD alternative works.
- Set up ID, Name (String(20)) and Memo fields on the TClientDataSet as shown in the code
- Add a TBSynEdit connected via the TDataSource to the Memo Field.  The purpose of this
  is to show that the live-bound TSynMemo which we'll add next performs in the same way
- Add a TSynMemo, TMemo, TBindingList, TBindSourceDB, and TBindNavigator to the form
- Use the quick-binding pop-up to add TLinkControlToFields to link the TSynEdit and the TMemo
  to the Memo field of the ClientDataSet
- Connect the `*` property of the BindSourceDB to the `*` property of the TBindNavigator in the visual LB designer.

Now, add the code below to the Form.  To save having to register our TSynMemo
descendant as a component and install it in the IDE, the code declares it
in the form unit as an `Interposer class`.  It implements all the obsever methods
that seem to be necessary to live-bind a TSynMemo.

Code

```
  type
    TSynMemo = class(SynMemo.TSynMemo)
    private
      procedure ObserverToggle(const AObserver: IObserver; const Value: Boolean);
    protected
      procedure DoChange; override;
      function CanObserve(const ID: Integer): Boolean; override;                       { declaration is in System.Classes }
      procedure ObserverAdded(const ID: Integer; const Observer: IObserver); override; { declaration is in System.Classes }
    end;

    TForm2 = class(TForm)
      ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
      DataSource1: TDataSource;
      DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
      DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
      SynMemo1: TSynMemo;
      ClientDataSet1ID: TIntegerField;
      ClientDataSet1Name: TStringField;
      ClientDataSet1Memo: TMemoField;
      BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
      BindNavigator1: TBindNavigator;
      Memo1: TMemo;
      BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB;
      LinkControlToField1: TLinkControlToField;
      LinkControlToField2: TLinkControlToField;
      DBSynEdit1: TDBSynEdit;
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    public
    end;

  [...]implementation[...]

  function TSynMemo.CanObserve(const ID: Integer): Boolean;
  { Controls which implement observers always override TComponent.CanObserve(const ID: Integer). }
  { This method identifies the type of observers supported by TObservableTrackbar. }
  begin
    case ID of
      TObserverMapping.EditLinkID,      { EditLinkID is the observer that is used for control-to-field links }
      TObserverMapping.ControlValueID:
        Result := True;
    else
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TSynMemo.DoChange;
  begin
    inherited;
    TLinkObservers.ControlChanged(Self);
  end;

  procedure TSynMemo.ObserverAdded(const ID: Integer; const Observer: IObserver);
  begin
    if ID = TObserverMapping.EditLinkID then
      Observer.OnObserverToggle := ObserverToggle;
  end;

  procedure TSynMemo.ObserverToggle(const AObserver: IObserver; const Value: Boolean);
  var
    LEditLinkObserver: IEditLinkObserver;
  begin
    EXIT;  //  do nothing
  end;

  const
    sDfm = 'DFM';

  procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'ID';
    ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;

    ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([1, 'Row1', 'Memo1']);
    ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([2, 'Row2', 'Memo two']);

  end;

  initialization

    Data.Bind.Components.RegisterObservableMember(TArray<TClass>.Create(
      TSynMemo
      ),
      'Lines.Text', sDfm);

  finalization

    Data.Bind.Components.UnregisterObservableMember(TArray<TClass>.Create(TSynMemo));

  end.
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't reproduce it, too because i'm working with TFDconnection and TFDtable. Could you share this project?
I understand that i need the Interposer and how to create, but you do it in main unit and use livebinding designer?

Comment: Using FireDAC components should make no difference to whether this answer works or not. Idon;t understand what you are asking when you say " but you do it in main unit and use livebinding designer?"

Comment: Sorry for my english. Is all this code in main unit? Can i create this bidirectional connection using the Livebinding designer? Because it does not working for me.

Comment: I just updated the code to replace the TClientDataSet by a TFDMemTable, changed the BindSourceDB1 to point at it and the project still works fine, so I'd be grateful if you would accept this answer (by clicking the "tick" icon) because it *does* answer your q as posted.  If you are having trouble applying it to an FDTable, you should post a new q asking about that.

Comment: Yes,  **all** the code is in the main unit, as the code clearly shows.  Which bi-directional connection are you asking about?  If you create a new project exactly following the steps in my answer, it will "just work".

Comment: It works now for me if i create livebinding with memo1 or create empty livebinding from popup and then in Text editor of Form I manually set from Memo1 to SynMemo1. It is acceptable for me.
That is why i ask, if You are using one unit, because i still cannot make connection via pop-up and i suspect Delphi that they suggests modified component only if it is in another unit.

Comment: Well, the only reason I used an interposer class in my answer was to make it self-contained and not require installing the TSynEdit descendant as a component.  But you should be easily able to put it in a separate unit, install it in a package and then have TYourSynEdit on the palette.  I can't see any reason why it wouldn't then fully support the IDE LB Visual designer.